# WPF textbox expression bindings

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have two textboxes bound to a slider. I want the second textbox to be 1.2 time the value of the slide.

```
<Slider Maximum="500" Minimum="25" TickFrequency="5" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Name="slCellHeight" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slCellHeight, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" Name="txtCellHeight" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slCellHeight, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="40" Name="txtCellWidth" />
```

That is, when the slider shows 100, the first textbox(txtCellHeight) should show 100. This is working fine. I want to the second one to be 120.

I tried the [calBinding](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding) but no success. Please suggest some good ways to do that.

Comment: use IValueConverter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a converter.

**XAML:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiplyConverter x:Key="MultiplyConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=slCellHeight, Path=Value,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource
MultiplyConverter}, ConverterParameter=1.2 }" Width="40" Name="txtCellWidth" />
```

**Class MultiplyConverter:**

```
class MultiplyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double result;
        double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out result);
        double mult = (double)value * result;
        return mult;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I've done it on the fly, so maybe it will need some fixes to compile.